# VSCode not recognising the Javascript file path in my folder

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have developed a basic HTML file and a JS file in a folder in ***Visual Studio Code***. Please find below the folder structure.

[image]

I am trying to refer the JS file from the HTML using `<script src="*//js file path//*">`. Unfortunately, I am not able to access the JS file. However, I tried the same scenario in **Notepad++, Sublime Text & Brackets.** to check if I was doing something wrong. It worked in the very first shot.

Any idea why this issue is occuring in VS Code ? Thanks in advance.

*P.S. I am using Ubuntu 15.10*

Comment: What's your `*//js file path//*`

Comment: Thanks for showing interest.Tried a couple of of them:

**1** ../main.js

**2**. entire root path of the file

Comment: Try `<script src="main.js">`

Comment: Tried this as well, but failed.
** All of them are failing only in VSCode. For rest of editors, it works fine **